# What kind of adapter do I need to hook up garden hose inside?

Tags: hose

What piece do I need to make this functional for the garden hose outside (standard shrinking type garden hose that goes into every outside outlet).

This seems too shallow and it won’t hold the hose.

The photo shows the measurements, the radius looks like it measures to about 3cm. Looks like an old laundry hookup?

So interested! It’s next to the current sink… from a house build in the 50’s/60’s

[image]

Comment: Should work as-is, I'd think. A washer hose should be the same as a garden hose.

Comment: Looks stock garden/laundry (which are same) hose connection to me. What do you mean that it "won't hold the hose?" - are you missing the washer in the hose end so it leaks?

Comment: Maybe you just need a wire brush to scrape all the paint off the threads so your hose will mate and seal properly. But, yeah, please [edit] to tell us _exactly_ what "won't hold the hose" means.

Comment: Standard hose bibbs, as commented, same thread as garden hose.

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S. that is a 3/4” pipe size but it takes a o-ring or flat washer to seal a hose fitting. I have seen lots of folks try to seal with Teflon pipe tape of PFTE but that won’t help--the seal for a hose is on the end, not the threads. I don’t know if there are different metric sides as I have heard of British straight thread that is slightly different than NPT.

Answer (score 0):

There is an adaptor needed. It screws onto the tap thread, using a flat washer or o-ring between. It has a male fitting on the other end. That also has an o-ring integral. Then you'll need the female adaptor which fits on the end of the hosepipe - several different diameter adaptors are available, all of which will go between hose and tap male.

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @HotLicks - UK and most of Europe at least. With a bit of profile filling, maybe answers could be more helpful...